# I installed MySQL on Lion OSX. How to connect it now to a Rails app/from terminal?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, osx-lion

I have installed MySQL database on Lions OSX system - the installation according to [this](http://databases.about.com/od/shareware/ht/Installing-Mysql-On-Mac-Os-X-10-7-Lion.htm) tutorial.

I am trying just to connect to MySQL in terminal - like this:

```
mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

During the installation I was not asked for setting up a password. How to set it up now?

Comment: if you did not set up a password try mysql -u root -p (blank) then press enter again. 1045 is authentication failed

Comment: But where to set up the password?

Comment: for setting up the mysql password you have two options: a. [mysqladmin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqladmin.html) or - once you're logged in - do an `update mysql.user set password=password('whatever') where User='root';`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson if the issue was at permission level then you wouldn't get a mysql error but an OS error such as Permission Denied.

Comment: @JoeMinichino You are right of course, I was thinking PostgreSQL that in many base installations uses ident for authentication.

Comment: When I try `mysqladmin -u root password MY_PASSWORD`, I get `mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'` - any tip how to get over this?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html ?

Comment: if you managed to connect with `mysql -u root -p` then update the password with the query above.

Comment: I have still troubles with this thing. `mysqladmin -u root password NEW_PASSWORD` produce `mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!`... `mysql -u root -p` produce `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)` - any tips how to get rid of these errors?